# Mapping specific field to a string

Tags: sqlite, split, common-table-expression

I have a table in SQLite named `Clients`:

| ID | Name | Hobbies | SubHobbies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Anne | sports, fashion | shoes, swimming |
| 2 | Max | eating, automative | desserts, cars |

I split the `Hobbies` column using Common Table Expressions (`with split() as`) :

| ID | Name | Hobbies | SubHobbies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Anne | sports | shoes, swimming |
| 1 | Anne | fashion | shoes, swimming |
| 2 | Max | eating | desserts, cars |
| 2 | Max | automative | desserts, cars |

Now I also want to split the `Subhubbies` column, which I can do using CTE. The format I want is (Swimming is a subhubby of Sports, shoes-Fashion, desserts-eating and cars-automative) :

| ID | Name | Hobbies | SubHobbies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Anne | sports | swimming |
| 1 | Anne | fashion | shoes |
| 2 | Max | eating | desserts |
| 2 | Max | automative | cars |

There are many clients, hobbies and sub-hobbies in this table so I don't want to do this one by one. Any ideas for splitting and placing them in the right place with queries?

Comment: I suggest not handling this in SQLite.  Bring your data into the database in the format you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the Hobbies table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Hobbies (
  `Hobby` TEXT,
  `SubHobby` TEXT
);

INSERT INTO Hobbies
  (`Hobby`, `SubHobby`)
VALUES
  ('sports', 'swimming'),
  ('fashion', 'shoes'),
  ('eating', 'desserts'),
  ('automative', 'cars');
```

You should have this table anyway, because otherwise your Clients table is not normalized. Then you run this query against the Clients/Hobbies tables:

```sql
SELECT c.ID, c.Name, h.Hobby, h.SubHobby
FROM Clients AS c, Hobbies AS h
WHERE instr(' ' || c.SubHobbies || ',', ' ' || h.SubHobby || ',')
```

Depending on your data, simple `WHERE instr(c.SubHobbies, h.SubHobby)` might also do just fine.